# Interfacing Aduino Nano and RDM8800

Tags: arduino-nano, rfid, firmware

I'm attempting to use an Arduino Nano with the RDM8800 to read data from NFC tags. After soldering wires between the Nano and the RDM8800, I attempted to test these devices using code similar to what has been used successfully on other serial devices similar to the RDM8800. Below is the code I used to test.

Wiring:

```
Nano - RDM8800
--------------
 5V  -  5V
GND  -  GND
 D3  -  TX
 D2  -  RX
```

Tags Tested:

- NTAG 216 (ISO14443A)
- MiFare Classic 1k (ISO14443A)

Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial soft(2,3);

void setup() {
  soft.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(soft.available() > 0) {
    String serialData = soft.readString();
    Serial.println(serialData);
    writeAck();
  }

}

void writeAck() {
  uint8_t payload[] = "ACK|0|\n";
  soft.write(payload, sizeof(payload));
}
```

I watched the serial monitor and attempted to scan two different NFC tags that matched the ISO14443A compatibility that should ship with the RDM8800, according to [this](https://www.itead.cc/blog/introduction-to-rdm8800-a-13-56mhz-configurable-rfid-module) article. I got no information returned on the serial monitor.

After, assuming the issue is with the firmware, I attempted to upload the firmware to the RDM8800, with no success. I installed the needed board support to the Arduino IDE, as outlined in [the intro article](https://www.itead.cc/blog/introduction-to-rdm8800-a-13-56mhz-configurable-rfid-module). Not having a USB to serial tool, I used another Nano and simply bridged the connection between the GND and RST pins. I was unable to upload the firmware to the RDM8800, getting the error below each time I tried.

Error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I believe that it's possible that I can't upload the firmware to the RDM8800 because the setup I used with the Nano as the USB to serial tool lacked a reset button. The image in [the intro article](https://www.itead.cc/blog/introduction-to-rdm8800-a-13-56mhz-configurable-rfid-module), says to connect the TX RX GND 5V and RST pins, but the image that it says shows this only shows the TX RX GND and 5V pins connected(See below).

Image:
[image]

The information that I've found on the RDM8800 and its use is very limited and so is my knowledge on this topic. I'm unsure how I should proceed right now. I believe that I'm taking the right approach to setup code to scan NFC tags, but I could be wrong there. I'm very unsure on what I'm doing in relation to the potential firmware issue. Overall, I'm simply unsure on how to proceed and I'm looking for more knowledgeable people to give me some advice on how to proceed.

Relevant Resources:
[RDM8800 Itead Wiki Page](https://www.itead.cc/wiki/RDM8800)
[RDM8800 Data Sheet](ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/Modules/IM131218001/DS_IM131218001.pdf)
[RDM8800 Schematic](ftp://imall.iteadstudio.com/Modules/IM131218001/SCH_IM131218001.pdf)
[RDM8800 Introduction Article](https://www.itead.cc/blog/introduction-to-rdm8800-a-13-56mhz-configurable-rfid-module)

Comment: your code is set to communicate to pins that are different than your actual connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoftwareSerial constructor is rx pin first then tx pin.

You have `SoftwareSerial soft(2,3);` But you said that

```
D3 - TX
D2 - RX
```

Which means soft rx is going to its rx and soft tx is going to its tx. These need to be swapped. Either swap the wires or change it to:

```
SoftwareSerial soft(3,2);
```